# Retrieve multiple objects from a buffer in C#

Tags: c#, sockets, serialization, asynchronous, buffer

First things first, let me explain my situation: I'm working on a client and a server in C# which use socket for communication.

For practical reason, I use the asynchronous part of both socket to transmit binary serialized objects from the client to the server and vice-versa.

My problem is that when I send too much object at once, the receiver object "stack" into the buffer and when I try to unserialize the buffer content, it give me only one object.

My question is : How can I separate each object from a buffer ?

Here is my `ReceiveCallback` function :

```
private void ReceiveMessageCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        Socket socket = (Socket)asyncResult.AsyncState;
        try
        {
            int read = socket.EndReceive(asyncResult);
            if (read > 0)
            {
                Log("Reception of " + read + " Bytes");

                // Jumper is an object that I use to transport every message
                Jumper pod = Common.Serializer.DeSerialize<Jumper>(this.readbuf);

                Buffer.SetByte(this.readbuf, 0, 0);
                socket.BeginReceive(this.readbuf, 0, this.readbuf.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveMessageCallback), socket);

                //We fire an event to externalise the analyse process
                Receiver(pod, socket);
            }
        }
        catch (SocketException ex)
        {
            if (ex.SocketErrorCode == System.Net.Sockets.SocketError.ConnectionReset)
            {
                socket.Close();
                Log("Distant socket closed");
            }
            else
                Log(ex.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The problem is probably in the sender code. Could you post the code that sends the object? Make sure you flush the socket after every object is sent out

Comment: @GETah +1 for having the same idea, with more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deserialization will consume your buffer for one object, and will left 'read pointer' of the buffer at the start of the next object.

My suggestion would be to either:

- move data from socket stream to some other (memory) buffer and deserialize from there, and have control over whole 'buffering' by hand

or

- when you get a callback, call deserialize several times in a row, until you get an exception.

Second approach will most likely fail because nobody can guarantee that you will always get WHOLE objects in one go, since stream that is attached to a socket is a sequence of bytes, and it can be broken at any point.

Hope that makes some sense.

EDIT:

In fact, the proper thing to do this would be to encapsulate each 'message' (serialized object on sending) into a packet, in which for example you'll have a small header telling you LENGTH of the packet, and upon reception, you will read the socket stream until you have complete packet data, then serialize.  And then the next packet, and so on.

EVEN MORE:

Say you send data at a rate of 1000 bytes at the sender side into the socket.  On the receiving side, you'll probably NEVER get 1000 by 1000 bytes out of the socket, in fact you can expect that only under two conditions:

- delay between each send is very large, and in between sends read occurs at receiver
- pure accident

Comment: Just because you receive some data from the socket does not mean you have received all data from your logical transaction. I agree with part 1 and the EDIT. Keep track of your data with a length counter. Read into a buffer until you make sure you have received all of your data. Then deserialize the objects in your logical transaction.